# How to set property of variable that is passed from GoogleAppsScript to a HTML page

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have looked at StackOverflow code on passing variables but still get this error.

```
function doGet() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var example = ss.getRange("T1").getDisplayValue();
var exampleText = "Some Text " + example; 

html.exampleVar = exampleText;
html.setTitle("Dynamic Webpage");

var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();

return html; 

}
```

The HTML file in Body tags is as follows

```
<?= exampleVar ?>
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property "exampleVar" of undefined to "Example Text". (line 8, file "Example", project "Example")

I realise I have not declared exampleVar as a variable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `html` isn't defined until after you've executed that line. Look at the order of your script lines.

Comment: I tried that as well @tehhowch - it then came up with an error that it could not connect to the server. Calling the function has worked well.

Comment: It was likely malformed HTML that was being evaluated. Note that "`'Server Error'` while running this line" is a completely different error than `TypeError`. Your code here shows normal printing scriptlets `<?=` content. You may have wanted to use [force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets). In any case, your issue is more than likely solved by reviewing the official documentation and the guide on variables with templates: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates

Comment: Thanks @tehowch I wan't familiar with force-printing scriptlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you trying to accomplish but I think this is how your example will work.

```
function doGet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Some Specific Sheet Name');
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate().setTitle("Dynamic Webpage");
  html.append(Utilities.formatString('<div id="exampletxt"><p>Some Text %s</p></div>', sh.getRange('T1')));
  return html; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper I was definitely missing Utilities.formatString

Answer (score 0):

Made a separate function to call the variables. Then called that function from the HTML file.

[How to pass an html variable to htmlservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190180/how-to-pass-an-html-variable-to-htmlservice)